# How to wait for all matrix job runs to successfully complete a specific step before executing the next step?

Tags: python, github-actions

I have a GitHub Action workflow that releases wheels for a Python package to the PyPI using multiple platforms and Python versions. It looks something like this abbreviated version:

```
jobs:
  build:
    name: build py3.${{ matrix.python-version }} on ${{ matrix.platform || matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      fail-fast: true
      matrix:
        os:
          - ubuntu
          - macos
          - windows
        python-version:
          - "8"
          - "9"
          - "10"
        include:
          - os: ubuntu
            platform: linux
          - os: windows
            ls: dir

    runs-on: ${{ format('{0}-latest', matrix.os) }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # This is the step that must be successful for all matrix job runs
      - name: test
      ...

      # I want to wait until all job runs in the matrix have successfully completed tests before running this step
      - name: release
      ...
```

What I want is for no job runs in the matrix to move on to the second step, until ALL runs have completed the testing step without errors. This is so that no wheels get published on PyPI if there is some sort of error. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You can use `jobs.<job_id>.needs` to require one job to be successful before another runs: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds

Comment: @NickODell would you suggest then that I break this into two separate jobs, one that builds and tests the wheels, and another that rebuilds and releases the wheels? Is there any way to reuse the wheel files, without just rebuilding them all again in the second job?

Comment: 1) Yes, I would. 2) I think [artifact storage](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts) can do that.